# Default structure padding by C compilers

Tags: c, struct

I know that C compilers do structure padding by default. I also know that one can disable structure padding, though this
is not recommended and even prohibited for some CPU architectures. I was wondering why structure padding is taking place and what are the advantages of it?

Comment: Well, it's simply faster for the cpu to put in register an integer where it is align, so compiler align stuff most at possible to optimize for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the advantages of structure padding?

Variables put on machine-aligned addresses can be read or written in fewer assembly instructions — usually one. Thus, the compiler uses padding to optimize its access.

Comment: If cpu supports unaligned loads and stores, there is no need to insert additional instructions. But loading/storing is still faster for aligned data, even if difference might be very small on some architectures. Unaligned load has to fetch two chunks of data for some cases.

Comment: A smaller need for cpu instructions in case of padded structs makes sense! In that case the advantage is reduced cpu cycles which leads to less power consumption and faster processing.